# Preserve input values after dynamically adding an input field

Tags: javascript

I'm making a form where it's possible to add extra input fields. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper-comp-setting" id="flashcard-list">
        <div class="fc-item">
          <label class="label setting-label" for="flashcards">Flashcard (1)</label>
          <input class="input setting-input" name="front" id="front" placeholder="Front" type="text" />
          <input class="input setting-input" name="back" id="back" placeholder="Back" type="text" />
        </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add flashcard" />
```

JS:

```
var fc_number = 1;
function add_fields() {
    fc_number++;
    document.getElementById('flashcard-list').innerHTML += '<div class="fc-item"><label class="label setting-label" for="flashcards">Flashcard (' + fc_number + ')</label> <input class="input setting-input" name="front" id="front" placeholder="Front" type="text" />\n<input class="input setting-input" name="back" id="back" placeholder="Back" type="text" /></div>\r\n';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hmxdmaL8/

My problem is that every time I add a new field the values from the previous fields disappear. How can I preserve those values?

Thank you for reading.
Cheers!

Comment: You should not create elements with same ID. ID needs to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmxdmaL8/1/)***

You cannot have multiple ID on the same page `#front` and `#back`.
Your issue is that you're resetting and element's innerHTML - loosing the input states and values

Instead use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML
with the `beforeend` property, that way you'll simply *append* new created elements to the DOM

```
<div class="wrapper-comp-setting" id="flashcard-list">

    <div class="fc-item">
        <label class="label setting-label" for="flashcards">Flashcard (1)</label>
        <input class="input setting-input" name="front" placeholder="Front" type="text" />
        <input class="input setting-input" name="back"  placeholder="Back" type="text" />
    </div>

    <!-- use insertAdjacentHTML on #flashcard-list -->    

</div>
<input type="button" id="more_fields" value="Add flashcard" />

<script>
    var addFieldButton = document.getElementById("more_fields");
    var flashCardList  = document.getElementById('flashcard-list')
    var fc_number = 1;

    function add_fields() {
        fc_number++;
        var fields = '<div class="fc-item">\n\
        <label class="label setting-label" for="flashcards">Flashcard (' + fc_number + ')</label>\n\
        <input class="input setting-input" name="front" placeholder="Front" type="text" />\n\
        <input class="input setting-input" name="back" placeholder="Back" type="text" />\n\
        </div>';
        flashCardList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", fields );
    }

    addFieldButton.addEventListener("click", add_fields);
</script>
```

Your other question was "why you cannot set `<script>` with your function **after** (like before `</body>` as you should) the button calling the `onclick` event":
that's cause on parse-time the `onclick="add_fields();"` could not find that function to be bound to. Use like I did, keeping your template clean of inline JS, and using event delegation with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper-comp-setting" id="flashcard-list">
    <div class="fc-item" data-index='1'>
      <label class="label setting-label" for="flashcards">Flashcard (1)</label>
      <input class="input setting-input" name="front" placeholder="Front" type="text" />
      <input class="input setting-input" name="back" placeholder="Back" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="more_fields" value="Add flashcard" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('#more_fields').click(function() {
    var x = $('#flashcard-list');
    var last_row_index = $('#flashcard-list div').last().data('index');
    var new_no = last_row_index + 1;
    var newrow = $('#flashcard-list div').last().clone(true);
    newrow.data('index', new_no);
    newrow.find('.label').text('Flashcard ' + '(' + new_no + ')');
    newrow.find('input').val('');
    x.append(newrow);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNXxQP

Comment: jQuery = Javascript, but this Question was tagged JavaScript and JavaScript != jQuery - Try always to provide a JS solution to the problem before suggesting external libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Roko, i will follow that from next time. I am a new bie here.

Answer (score -1):

you can try jQuery insertAfter() Method

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("<span>data inserted here</span>").insertAfter("p");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Insert value</button>

<p>one.</p>
<p>two.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I've said to Runny, jQuery is always a good library to use, but let's first provide answers on the specified tag - before suggesting JS libraries like jQuery, Mootools etc etc etc... Also sometimes loading a huge library instead of using plain JavaScript is not a good suggestion... depends, you got the idea.

Answer (score -2):

```js
var fc_number = 1;
function add_fields() {
    fc_number++;
    debugger;
    $("#flashcard-list").append('<div class="fc-item"><label class="label setting-label" for="flashcards">Flashcard (' + fc_number + ')</label> <input class="input setting-input" name="front" id="front" placeholder="Front" type="text" />\n<input class="input setting-input" name="back" id="back" placeholder="Back" type="text" /></div>\r\n')
}


$("#more_fields").on("click",function(){
add_fields();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- had to put the script here because I was getting a "add_fields() not defined" error. Anybody knows why? -->
<div class="wrapper-comp-setting" id="flashcard-list">
        <div class="fc-item">
          <label class="label setting-label" for="flashcards">Flashcard (1)</label>
          <input class="input setting-input" name="front" id="front" placeholder="Front" type="text" />
          <input class="input setting-input" name="back" id="back" placeholder="Back" type="text" />
        </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add flashcard" />
```

and use the jquery code for this too it is not tricky as 
such as Javascript. its work fine here and sorry for contributing in jquery.

Comment: Please avoid answering in jQuery on specifically JS tagged questions.  
Try also to provide code within your question. jsFiddle is not in relationship with StackOverflow. If it closes it's services or the link dies, your question would be useless in any case.

Comment: @ Roko  i knw you ill do this for Sure but i have given the alternate and easy one, y down count? i have informed prior

Comment: Runny, StackOverflow is meant to be used to find answers on problems. We cannot afford people searching for a vanilla JS answers and end up reading bunch of answers that use jQuery only. There's also other ways to do the above in JavaScript, if you covered those cases I think you'd not get that nasty downvote :(

Comment: So *jQuery might be OK* as an **option** (like you did) but after showing a valid solution on the specific tag.